Algebraic Hartogs's lemma for dimension 1 rings

I am reading the proof of what Vakil calls "algebraic Hartogs's lemma" which says that if $A$ is an integrally closed, integral, Noetherian ring, then $$A=\bigcap A_{\mathfrak{p}},$$ where the intersection runs over the prime ideals of codimension $1$. 
During the proof, Vakil claims that this is "vacuously" true for dimension $1$ rings, and I am struggling to see why. 
Any help is appreciated.

For a Noetherian one dimensional domain, the ring is the intersection of its localizations at all maximal ideals.

Hartogs, not "Hartog", is the name of the mathematician. So if Vakil is spelling the possessive as "Hartog's", then someone ought to get in contact with him. I would recommend either Hartogs's, or "the algebraic Hartogs lemma".

@user43208 my bad, I misread let me fix it

In the dimension $1$ case, $A$ is a Dedekind domain. More specifically, if $A$ has dimension $1$, then any nonzero prime $\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal, since $0 < \mathfrak{p}$ is then a chain of prime ideals in $A$. But any domain $R$ has $R = \bigcap_{\mathfrak{m}} R_{\mathfrak{m}}$, where the intersection runs over all maximal $\mathfrak{m}\subset R$. (For a proof of the last statement, note that the injection $R \to \bigcap R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is surjective when localized at any $\mathfrak{m}$.)
